# subprocess сколько занимает памяти процесс - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, процесс, subprocess, ram

Kак рассчитать сколько оперативной памяти занимает процесс запущенный через subprocess?

```py
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(program, shell = True)
poll = process.poll()

while poll != None:
  #if process in RAM > memory_limit:
    process.kill()
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто задать ограничение по памяти:

```
import resource

MAX_VIRTUAL_MEMORY = 10 * 1024 * 1024 # 10 MB

def limit_virtual_memory():
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (MAX_VIRTUAL_MEMORY, resource.RLIM_INFINITY))

p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l', '/'], preexec_fn=limit_virtual_memory)
p.communicate()
```

Подробнее [здесь](https://gist.github.com/s3rvac/f97d6cbdfdb15c0a32e7e941f7f4a3fa)

Comment: а как сделать что бы знать сколько занято памяти?